# Suppose $f \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb R)$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n!} \int_0^a x^n f^{(n+1)}(a-x)dx=0.$ Show $f$ is analytic on $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion, analyticity

> Suppose that $f \in C^{\infty} (-\infty , \infty)$ and that
>   $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n!} \int_0^a x^n f^{(n+1)}(a-x)dx=0$$
>   for all $a\in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $f$ is analytic on $(-\infty , \infty)$ and 
>   $$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}x^k, \hspace{1cm} x\in \mathbb{R}$$

I have the theorem:
If $f \in C^{\infty}(a,b)$ and $f^{(n)}(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in (a,b)$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$, the $f$ is analytic on $(-\infty ,\infty)$ and
$$f(x) = f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(k)}(x_0)}{k!}x^k$$

If I can show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n!} \int_0^a x^n f^{(n+1)}(a-x)dx=0 \Rightarrow f^{(n)}(x) \geq 0$ then I think I would apply this theorem and be done, but I am not sure how to do that. Any help would be appreciated, or if this isn't the correct way to go about this a nudge in the right direction would be nice as well.

Comment: The condition just says that the remainder term in the Taylor approximation tends to $0$.

Comment: Ok. Then$$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(k)}(x_0)}{k!}(x-x_0)^k$$ So I can set  $x_0=0$ so I get the sum I want and then it is analytic because the power series converges to $f$? @DanielFischer

Comment: Right. The remainder term converging to $0$ is equivalent to the Taylor series converging to $f$. And that means $f$ is analytic.

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel Fischer observed, the expression   $$ \frac{1}{n!} \int_0^a x^n f^{(n+1)}(a-x)dx=0$$ is exactly the remainder of Taylor series with center at $0$, evaluated at $a$. This is the [integral form of the remainder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor's_theorem#Explicit_formulae_for_the_remainder). To prove it, notice that after subtracting off the Taylor polynomial of degree $\le n$, we end up with a function $g$ whose first $n$ derivatives vanish at $0$; then integrate $g(a)=\int_0^a g'(x)\,dx$ a bunch of times.

Since the given condition says that the remainder goes to zero, the function $f$ is represented by its Taylor series centered at $0$, and therefore is analytic.